# Compiler Errors in atlwin.h

Tags: c++, atl, wtl

When including atlwin.h from the Microsoft ATL libraries in Visual Studio 2013 building will result in numerous complier errors about undefined elements.

i.e.

```
#include <atlwin.h>
class MainWnd : public CWindowImpl<MainWnd>
{};
```

> "CWindowImpl: base class is not defined" error.

or

> HMONITOR is not defined

This does not occur when building using VS2010.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Totally briliant question that unlocks the compilation of some old ATL samples.  Very welcome as is the answer.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is with the targeted version of windows in the stdafx.h file

from MSDN

> Visual C++ no longer supports targeting Windows 95, Windows 98,
>   Windows ME, or Windows NT. If your WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT macros are
>   assigned to one of these versions of Windows, you must modify the
>   macros. When you upgrade a project that was created by using an
>   earlier version of Visual C++, you may see compilation errors related
>   to the WINVER or _WIN32_WINNT macros if they are assigned to a version
>   of Windows that is no longer supported.

So, changing

```
#ifndef WINVER  
#define WINVER 0x0400   
#endif
```

to

```
#ifndef WINVER  
#define WINVER 0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
#endif
```

corrects the build problem

Answer (score 4):

`CWindowImpl` is defined in `<atlwin.h>`, so you need to include that. I don't know what the file `atldwin.h` that you're including is, but apparently it doesn't contain that class.

Edit: According to a comment below by CCondron, this is due to targeting versions of Windows no longer supported by Visual C++. To fix, add:

```
#define WINVER 0x0500 
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500
```

Comment: I'm sorry, that's typo. I am including atlwin.h, but it's not working

Comment: If you have a type in your code then you obviously didn't test the code posted in the question, so you can't even know that it gives this error.

Comment: I have a type in my code, because I was writing it here partially by memory.

Comment: I know. And that makes your question useless because we don't know if the code you posted actually causes that error.

Comment: I'm 100% sure, that it causes this error, I checked it couple times by now.

Comment: Question is closed or I would add this as an answer: add #define WINVER 0x0500
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0500 see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sehtctf.aspx

Comment: To my mind, ridiculous to mark down and close a question about a compiler problem upgrading from VS2010 to VS2013.  I had exactly the same problem so many many thanks to @CCondron for supplying the answer.

Comment: @Stochastically The information about upgrading VS (as well as an additional error message) was added to the question by CCondron, and we don't know if it's the same issue the original poster had. I added the information to my answer in any case.

Comment: OK @interjay I see that in the edit history now :-).  But with CCondron's edits, don't you think that this question should be Open rather than Closed?

Comment: I created a new question for this, but it was down voted for being 'questionable' to post and an answer to a closed question so I removed it. Should I put it back up? Also the HMONITOR error is part of the errors reported for this problem, so I'm pretty sure it's the same.

Comment: My issue may be slightly different than the original one here but  I've tried to open another question about just the issue I've reported and got shut down for a duplicate question, So let's reopen this one already.